# Capybara::ElementNotFound, but it is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, bdd, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the following error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "username"
./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do
  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
  context 'creating a new session' do
    it 'can set the current_user variable to the logged user' do
      visit '/login'
      fill_in 'username', with: 'gabrielhilal' #I have tried `Username` as well
      fill_in 'password', with: 'secret'
      click_button 'Login'
      current_user.should == @user
      current_user.username.should == 'gabrielhilal'
    end
  end
  context 'destroying existing session' do
    xit 'can destroy the current_user' do
    end
  end
end
```

But I have the field `username` in my form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" / <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="x7ORLDIvq1BXr8SOkd/Zla9Pl5R5tBXAtyflCpTGCtY=" /></div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Login" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I did a similar test with `cucumber` and it is passing, which confirms that the field `username` is there: [When to switch from cucumber to rspec in the BDD cycle for a login procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192413/when-to-switch-from-cucumber-to-rspec-in-the-bdd-cycle-for-a-login-procedure)

Any idea?

**EDIT** - I have added the `save_and_open_page`, which gives me a blank page. The `puts "#{page.html.inspect}"` also returns empity.

```
""

Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "username"
./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Try use save_and_open_page, with launchy gem

Comment: Thanks @hypee... I added the `save_and_open_page` and for some reason my page is blank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you've already answered your own question (kind of), but I feel it's still warranted to let you know that the example you've provided is a mixture of a controller and a request spec...

To quote verbatim from [RSpec - Controller Specs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#controller-specs):
`Note: To encourage more isolated testing, views are not rendered by default in controller specs.`

The main difference (in the way RSpec interprets what kind of spec it is) is the line: `describe SessionsController do`.

To align it with RSpec and Testing best practices:

1. Move the spec to `spec/requests`
2. Change the describe to `describe "SessionsController" do`
3. Remove `render_views`

your spec should run just fine...

Check out [RSpec - Request Specs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs) for what I mean. I would also check out [betterspecs.org](http://betterspecs.org) for ways you can improve on testing.

Answer (score 11):

You can debug it with terminal like:

```
it {puts page.body}
```

And see if there is 'username' input.
But I think that problem on the first step `visit '/login'`

Comment: I found this to be incredibly useful.  It tells you exactly which element is which and makes things incredibly easy to find. Thank you for sharing (even if it was years ago!)

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I have to explicitly tell my controller to render the views. I found it in the [rspec readme](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#controller-specs), so I solve the problem adding `render_views`.

```
describe SessionsController do
  render_views #this line solved the problem
  before :each do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just remove `block_unknow_urls` in `features/support/env.rb`:

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.allow_unknown_urls
end
```

Comment: I don't see how this has a relation to the question, please try to elaborate on why this works

Comment: Hi @Toby Zhen , Welcome to SO ! Please add more details and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer